# wherebetween 2 defferrent query laravel

Tags: php, laravel-8

i have 2 query in controller like this:

```
$bill_payment =BillPayment::whereIn('bill_id',$bill);
$invoice_payments=InvoicePayment::whereIn('invoice_id',$invoice);
```

and this code to get date:

```
if(!empty($request->from_date)&& !empty($request->until_date))
    {
        $bill_payment->whereBetween('date',  [$request->from_date, $request->until_date]);
        $invoice_payments->whereBetween('date',  [$request->from_date, $request->until_date]);
        $data['from_date']  = $request->from_date;
        $data['until_date'] = $request->until_date;

    }
$invoice_payment = $invoice_payments->get();
```

I can get just one of them in time. any help to get both **bill_payment** and **invoice_payments** in one **get**?

blade result code is like this :

```
@forelse($invoice_payment as $payment)
<tr>
<td>{{ Verta::instance($payment->date)->format('j F Y') }} </td>
<td>{{ \Auth::user()->invoiceNumberFormat($payment->invoice_id) }}
</td>
<td>{{ $payment->payment_type }} </td>
<td> {{ \Auth::user()->priceFormat($payment->amount) }}</td>
{{-- {{ dd($payment);}} --}}
</tr>
@empty
<tr>
<td colspan="6" class="text-center text-dark">
<p>{{ __('No Data Found') }}</p>
</td>
</tr>
@endforelse
```

and both table migration file like this (except bill_id change with invoice_id):

```
Schema::create('bill_payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('bill_id');
            $table->date('date');
            $table->float('amount')->default('0.00');
            $table->integer('account_id');
            $table->integer('payment_method');
            $table->string('reference');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: Is there any relationship between those two tables?

Comment: no . not right now

Comment: Can you share table structure?

Comment: I shared it .both table like each other  .

Comment: the deferent  is  just invoice_id and bill_id

Comment: What exact issue you're facing currently?

Comment: I want to show both table record in one foreach blade. but i get server error (500) . when i call one of them everything is ok .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253359/discussion-between-mehdi-bakhtiari-and-pragnesh-chauhan).